# Modify GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS at build time (run script phase)

Tags: xcode, bash, macros, c-preprocessor, xcodebuild

I have created a run script phase in XCode for one of my projects.
In that phase, I read/write plists and copy files to folders based on some parameters in my plist.

My app uses as well some GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS macros (e.g. #MAC1). I have a value in my plist files that says if I have to use that macro or not.
How can I update GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS based on the value of my plist file at build time? Basically, I just would like to append MAC1=1 or MAC1=0 to it.

Thanks